# when synchronized(xxx.class), where is the markword？

Tags: object, jvm, synchronized

I know that synchronized will used markword at object head, to mark the lock status, but when I use synchronized(xxx.class), Which markword am I using?

```
public void foo() {
    synchronized (Object.class) {
        System.out.println("object class");
    }
}
```

Comment: you set `synchronized (Object.class)` to mark that only 1 thread can use static methods (or attributes) at the same time

Comment: `Object.class` is an object instance of `java.lang.Class`. Like any other object in the heap, it has a header with a mark word.

Comment: In other words, you can also write `Object o = Object.class; synchronized(o) { … }`. Nothing strange here, you have an object, you can use that object for `synchronized`. Besides that, the markword is an implementation detail. It’s up to the particular JVM, how it will implement `synchronized`.

Comment: I have learned that synchronized used object head markword，markword will used by lock upgrade. and I want to know when I use static synchronized and synchronized(xxx.class), where is the markword? is the static synchronized method has a lock upgrade function?

Comment: It’s not clear what you don’t understand. In JVMs using a markword, every object has a markword and objects of type `Class` are still objects. So when you use `synchronized(xxx.class)`, the markword will be where it always is, in the object you just specified. Besides that, you can easily program without ever thinking about the fact that some JVM implementations use a markword. It’s entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @Holger thanks, before that, I didn’t know that the loaded class was also an object in the JVM